# postfix 2.11, cannot receive emails from specific domain

Tags: networking, dns, email, postfix, smtp

helo, I am  over 3 days now working on a solution. Our server is getting emails normally from around the world, except from one domain(our ISP free emails server domain). It would not be a problem but some of our customers use smtp of this provider to send emails.

The problem is that I do not see any incoming request logs from their server. And also, they do not get back any undelivered email reply.

I also created a special access list and included in smtpd conditions.

1. Where I can start debugging ? I can add info...
2. Where I can see/capture the blocked connection?

Thanks in advance...